# Index out of range in Swift with removeAtIndex

Tags: swift

I tried to remove an element in NSUserDefaults which is the same as stockSymbol's value when click a button. My idea is that cast the NSUserDefaults to an array and remove the element with removeAtIndex. Here is my code.

```
@IBAction func buttonFilledStarClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("Filled star clicked")
    self.buttonFilledStar.hidden = true
    self.buttonEmptyStar.hidden = false

    var Array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favorites")! as! [String]
    var countArray = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favorites")! as! [String]).count - 1


    for i in 0...countArray {
        if stockSymbol! == Array[i] {
            NSLog("i is : \(i)")
            Array.removeAtIndex(i)
        }
        else {}
    }

    NSLog("Array is: \(Array), countArray is: \(countArray)")

}
```

However it has 'out of index' error.
It works when I just comment `Array.removeAtIndex(i)` out.
Array looks like this -- 
["aa", "bb", "Test!", "Test!"]
Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to iterate from the back to the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not remove it from inside of the loop, when you call removeAtIndex(i) Array removes the item so you have 1 less item then countArray.. so you have to have another array to remember which item you want to remove and remove it outside of the loop.. or better option is to use filter

```
// Filter only strings that match stockSymbol
Array = Array.filter { $0 == stockSymbol! }
```

Answer (score 3):

So, the change you can make to resolve the error with the least impact on your code overall would be to simply iterate through the indices backwards:

```
for i in (0...countArray).reverse() {
    if stockSymbol! == Array[i] {
        NSLog("i is : \(i)")
        Array.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
    else {}
}
```

But the best option is to just use Swift's `filter`:

```
Array = Array.filter { $0 != stockSymbol }
```

---

*An expanded note on why the crash is happening...*

Let's take a simplified example.  Say I have the following `array`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And I want to remove all of the odd numbers out of it.  Using your first naïve approach, I might write my logic like this:

```
for i in 0..<arr.count {
    if arr[i] % 2 != 0 {
        arr.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}
```

Look at what happens on each iteration.

On the first iteration, we have `arr[i]` of `1`.  This is an odd number, so we'll `removeAtIndex`, and our array now actually looks like this:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The array's size is now smaller--it has just 9 elements.  But the loop doesn't work like an old C-style for loop where `i < arr.count` is checked on each iteration (which is part of why this loop is faster).

But notice something else that happens when we iterate forward...

On the second iteration, `i` is equal to `1`, and so what does `arr[i]` give us?  It gives us `3`.  We never even check `2`.  On the first iteration, when `i` was `0`, it was at index `1`.  On the second iteration, when `i` is `1`, the `2` is at index `0`.

So on the second iteration, we'll call `removeAtIndex` with `i` equal to `1` and remove the `3`.

This pattern will continue for a few iterations until we end up with our array of just even numbers:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

But this happens after the iteration where `i` was equal to `4`, and the loop is going to try running until `i` is equal to `10`.

On the sixth iteration of the loop, we try to access the element at index `5` of the array.  But the array only has five elements, so the largest index is `4`.  When we try to access index `5`, we crash.

Answer (score 2):

Try to find out which `i` that give you `index out of range` result. Is it the `0` or the last one. Maybe you will find some other useful clue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Array is a type, maybe you can call:

```
var favourites = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("favorites")! as! [String]
```

Then you don't need a array's count variable you can access using count arrays property.

Finally if you are iterating through an array and remove an element it always going to throw "index's error" because the index is not the same as the beginning..

For solving this you can take two pointers of the index variable, but what I would do is something like this:

```
var correctElements = favourites.filter({$0!=stockSymbol})
```