# Swift 4 - Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, random, indexoutofrangeexception

I need help for finalize my code in Swift 4:
I want to shuffle my questions array, but it always crashes after one time and shows this message:

> "Fatal error: Index out of range".

Here is my code:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    var questions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    var answers = [["1","2","3"],["2","1","3"],["3","2","1"],["1","3","2"],["2","3","1"]]

    // Variables
    var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
    var shuffled = [String]();
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random() % 5)

    // Label Question
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    // Buttons
    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)) {
            print ("RIGHT")
            newQuestion()
        }
        else {
            print ("WRONG")
            newQuestion()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        newQuestion()
    }

    // Functions
    func newQuestion() {
        Label.text = questions[randomNumber]   // ----------> Fatal error: Index out of range !!! -------------------------------------------------------------
        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(3)+1

        for _ in 0..<questions.count {
            let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
            shuffled.append(questions[randomNumber])
            questions.remove(at: randomNumber)
        }

    // Create a Button
    var Button:UIButton = UIButton()
    var x = 1
    for i in 1...3 {
        Button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
        if (i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)) {
            Button.setTitle(answers[randomNumber][0], for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            Button.setTitle(answers[randomNumber][x], for: .normal)
            x = 2
        }
    }
}
```

It seems there is a problem with my variable `randomNumber` but I don't understand how to fix it.
I have seen similar questions on the forum but no answer which resolves my problem.

Comment: Why does the first `for` loop in your `newQuestion` method delete all of your questions?

Comment: I deleted it and added my var "questions" into my function "newQuestion", so it works, but how can I do for it don't repeat twice the same "question"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index out of range in Swift with removeAtIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993571/index-out-of-range-in-swift-with-removeatindex)

Comment: You should be [swapping elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#Modern_method) in-place rather than deleting.  That will avoid the out of range error due to changing array size and also be more computationally efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you delete a member of an array while going trough that same array in a `for` loop, the `array.count` decreases, and you inevitably get `index out of range` error.

The common solution of this problem is to go through an array from end to beginning, using the `reversed()` function of `CountableRange`:

```
for _ in (0..<questions.count).reversed(){

    //YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: @Jamie Glad to hear that. If it works for you, please, accept my answer.

Comment: This is not the problem in this case. Since the value from the `CountableRange` is not even used the order does not matter.

Answer (score -3):

arc4random() returns a random number in the range of 0 to 4 294 967 295

drand48() returns a random number in the range of 0.0 to 1.0

arc4random_uniform(N) returns a random number in the range of 0 to N - 1

try 
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))